# Gatsby and Classnames library: Apply CSS class depending on content of div

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, class-names

I have a Gatsby project with a blog. I have a tag cloud section that shows the tags for blog posts. I also have a button/header on the actual blog post card that I want to style the same as it's corresponding tag in the tag cloud i.e. if there's a red tag for "Press Releases" in the tag cloud I want to style all blog post cards that are about Press Releases to have a red button, if there's a blue tag for "Getting Started" in the tag cloud then I want to style all blog post cards with the tag of Getting Started to be blue, and so on.

I have a PostCard component where blog post cards are styled. I am using the [Classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) library to apply CSS styles depending on the value of the tag, like this:

```
{post.tags && <div className={
                        classNames(styles.postCardTags, {
                            [tagStyles.hiddenTag]: primary_tag === `Data schema primary`,
                            [tagStyles.tagRed]: primary_tag === `Press Release`, 
                        })
                    }> 
                    <Tags post={post} visibility="public" autolink={false} />
                </div>}
```

The above code sets the default styles for tags to `postCardTags` (which I have set to blue), and it sets tags with a value of "Press Release" to red.

When I run this locally on `localhost:8000/` it correctly applies the styles, "Press Release" tags are correctly set to red. When I push to production, tags with a value of "Press Release" are not properly setting their CSS class to `tagStyles.red` and are blue. For some reason `tagStyles.red` is set for "Press Release" tags when the project is ran locally but when pushed to production "Press Release" tags are set to blue (i.e. `styles.postCardTags`).

Why are my "Press Release" tags applying the style `tagStyles.tagRed` when on `localhost` but applying the class `styles.postCardTags` when pushed to the live site? Is this an issue with how Gatsby builds the component?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an external package (that will be bundled increasing the project's size) to achieve this behavior. Removing the package may fix your problem since it may have SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering) issues. I use to change the class name depending on some parameters (like yours with `tags`) or `props`. Try:

```
let classNames= post.tags === 'Press Releases' ? 'red' : 'blue' // change it to styling modules

{post.tags && <div className={`defaultClass ${classNames}`}> 
                    <Tags post={post} visibility="public" autolink={false} />
                </div>
}
```

*Note: you can add your logic inside the `className` template literal but it's cleaner to use an external variable.*

I don't know how's your use-case, you can change the `post.tags === 'Press Releases'` for a `includes` function if needed.

As I said, you can change this behaviour to add CSS modules there.